# SQL-MYSQL Can't create Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I always get the error:

> CREATE DATABASE bundesliga ERRORCODE 1007 CANT CREATE DATABASE bundesliga, database exists

Here is my code:

```
CREATE DATABASE bundesliga;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Liga;

CREATE TABLE Liga (
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Spiel;
CREATE TABLE Spiel ();
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the database `bundesliga` already exists...

Comment: i should use the keyword USE....but why?

Comment: @user3669866 Use mean you [use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/use.html) the database for the next statement

Answer (score 7):

Your Database Bundesliga already exists.

you have to drop your database first and then recreate it.

```
    DROP DATABASE bundesliga;
    CREATE DATABASE bundesliga;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Liga;

    CREATE TABLE Liga (
    );
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Spiel;
    CREATE TABLE Spiel ();
```

or use this

```
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bundesliga;
```

and to check if database exist.

```
   SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'bundesliga';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to prevent the error:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bundesliga;
```

If the database already exists, this does nothing. If it doesn't exist, it will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Your database already exists.  See error code 1007 [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your Database Bundesliga already exists. If you want to recrate you have to drop this before.